# String Input Validation in Python

Tags: python, validation, input

I have having trouble coming up with a input validation for my string. I am having the user input 2 numbers. The user would input something like    "2(space)3". My validation would include having anything other than a number being inputted go back and re-enter their input. Not asking anyone to write the code, just let me know the easiest way to go about this, I have tried multiple different loops and if statements and not getting anywhere.

```
print ("\nEquation format: remainder dividor, for example 2 3 means x % 3 = 2\n")
for i in range(0, k):
    print ("Please input equation " + str(i+1))
    s = input()
    a_i, n_i = map(int, s.split())
    a.append(a_i)
    n.append(n_i)
```

Comment: I feel like a `while` loop is good for what you need.

Comment: while not user_input.isdigit(): user_input = input("Please input equation ")
should work fine for you, define user_input at the top of your code

Comment: What would i set user_input = to? user_input=()??

Comment: just a blank string will do ""

Comment: the problem i am getting is that it is saying that when i enter 4(space)7 it says it is not an integer. There has to be something i can add that detects my space.

Comment: while True:
                try:
                        userInput = int(input("Please input equation:"))
                except ValueError:
                        print("not an integer!")
This is what i have so far. I have initialized userInput=0